# Battery powered ionic air pump voltage stepup

Tags: dc, high-voltage

I am working on a proof-of-concept device for medical purposes, but am lacking in the electronics side of the skillset!

I am trying to build a vibration-free wearable air pump, and using an ionic thrust system seems like a potential success, since I don't need huge pressures (0.02-0.25PSI across only about 1/2in^2). There's not a lot of available documentation on ionic air thrust concepts, as the truly lucrative prospects (like transportation) are mostly out of scope for ion drives. However, I have found enough to suggest that I need at least 5.2kV to get the air to ionize enough to get things moving. BUT, a wearable really needs to be cordless and so I need to get some battery source stepped up to that neighborhood somehow.

I'm also curious as to people's theories about what might happen if the air direction is forcibly reversed by backwards pressure.

Comment: Upvoted because I like the idea. But worried as an ionic airpump is mostly electronics and you say you have no skills in that area. I think you should team up with somebody who knows electronics especially high voltage circuits.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get to that sort of voltage would be a flyback transformer to get you to a middling voltage, followed by a multiplier cascade to raise the voltage to the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

just search OEM 7Kv boost modules. They are cheap enough. if you operate them at their lowest dc input voltage you will probably get exactly the 4-5Kv you need. Or take apart one of those tennis racket bug zappers. Only one transister and a few caps and a small, generic transformer. Puts out 1Kv but will overheat if run continuously. If you want ionic pumping just get rid of the fat capacitor on the output side of the circuit. The circuit is simple enough for a total novice to copy and modify. Just choose a transistor with more current handling capacity and you can run it non-stop.